# What is the chemical composition of VOC's off-gassed from polyurethane?

Tags: organic-chemistry, polymers

I understand that all polyurethane (PU) materials off gas VOCs. I tried finding the % composition of the gases off-gassed by PU, but I am not able to get satisfactory answer. On the same note, why are these gases off-gassed?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the composition, but I suspect something bad like benzene.  My understanding is that these are residual solvent that was used during the synthesis of the polymer.

Comment: Is there way to find out which gases are emitted? In the first place, how I collect the gas for analysis? What test method can I use? Thanks!

Comment: You can pump down (vacuum) on a piece of the material in a Schlenk line, and then collect the leached gasses into a liquid nitrogen trap.  This can be dissolved into a solvent and subjected to GC/MS.